# regular expression not containing two or more consecutive comma or hyphen and between numbers at most one hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I have scenario to validate number range, it can be multiple range or single number.

Ex number 1 to 10 can be written as (1-3,4,5-8,9,10) here 1-3 indicates rage (1,2,3) I have tried java regex :

```
Pattern.matches("^[0-9][0-9,-]*,[0-9,-]*[0-9]$","11,131-132-134,45,12--10,,10");
```

this pattern allows consecutive hyphen and comma,

Valid Input

```
1) 1-3,4,5-8,9,10
2) 1-3,4-5,6-10
3) 1,2,3,4,5
4) 1,2-5,6
```

Invalid Input

```
1) ,2,3,4-10,
2) -2,3,4-10-
3) 2,3,,4-10
4) 2,3,4--10
5) 2,3,4-6-10 (Invalid range)
```

can someone suggest how to check the comma and hyphen should not appear two times consecutively, start and end with number, range should not repeat (4-8-10)

Comment: try this  - > "^[0-9][0-9,-]*[0-9]$"

Comment: `^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$` - But what about reverse ranges, like `8-5`? You can't validate numeric order with a regex.

Comment: @GovindMadhu your regex allows for example `1,,3` which is an invalid option for the OP.

Comment: You shouldn't add `<br>` tags for representing line breaks in a post. It's a markdown editor. @GovindMadhu

Comment: @revo : I didn't add them. The person who edited before me added that. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: @albciff :(?:[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?,)+(?:[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?$)

Answer (score 1):

This should be the regex you want:

```
^\\d+(-\\d+)?(,\\d+(-\\d+)?)*$
```

It checks for the following sequence:

`\\d+` : One or more digits

`(-\\d+)?` : An optional sequence of hyphen followed by one or more digits

`(,\\d+(-\\d+)?)*` : Zero or more occurrence of **a comma followed by one or more digits followed by an optional sequence of hyphen followed by one or more digits**

As the regex looks for a digit at the beginning, a string starting with hyphen or comma will not be allowed.

As it looks for a digit to be immediately followed by a hyphen and comma, a string having consecutive hyphens or commas, a hyphen immediately followed by a comma or the reverse would not be allowed.

As the `?` in `(-\\d+)?`allows exactly zero or one occurrence of the `(-\\d+)` sequence, a range like 1-2-3 will not be matched.

If you don't need to allow a single number alone, replace the `*` in `^\\d+(-\\d+)?(,\\d+(-\\d+)?)*$` with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

A repeated group is a simple way to validate a string of a repeating sequence:

```
(?:\\d+(?:-\\d+)?,)+(?:\\d+(?:-\\d+)?$)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG3aI1/1)